# Play Audio in Control Center ios7

Tags: ios7, avplayer, control-center

I am using AVPlayer to play audio files from the server.
  I pass the URL to the AV Player

But i cannot get the audio to play in the control center
Any ideas how to do it
I searched on stack over flow
People have mentioned about subscribing to remote notification
Is it the right way?

Comment: I just find this solution that works to received event from control center. It's works on IOS7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982292/ios-7-sdk-not-abiding-background-audio